# Show/Hide some markers in Google Maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the google maps plugin in flutter and would like when zooming out/zooming in some markers would be hidden/shown. After some research I found several things like "markers clustering" but, however, with this feature I can't hide just some markers.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: You wanted to hide markers that are not visible from the map viewport? Is that correct?

Comment: I just want to be able to hide and show just a few markers. For example, I have 15 markers and I want to be able to hide/show only 7 of these markers